# Unable to access database with Φ character in column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database

[image: Error in ODBC with line spatial data]

The sql server 2008 responded with the following error in some computer while other computer worked just fine.What is the cause of this error? There is difference in version though 6.01.7600 and 6.01.7601

> Actual column name is Azi_Direction_A_Φ but it is taking a
>   Azi_Direction_A_o is there any relation with unicode or installing unicode support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- The 2 machines are calling different SQL Server Instances with different schemas
- The same database changed between calls (is it reproducible?)

The ODBC driver is part of the OS since Windows XP so there should be no differences

Edit:

- Are regional settings the same on both PCs?
- Check the DSN setting for translations etc

Comment: I am calling same schema like myip\schema and I am using same db (it contains spatial data) in other computer

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to see what's different between the two machines:

1. Different schemas (one with that column, the other without)
2. ODBC driver versions.

Comment: where can I find the latest driver I think it is problem with the driver I looked at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16177